# R - convert JSON to desired format

Tags: json, r

My dataframe currently looks like this:

```
df$name <- c("Person A","Person B","Person C")
df$count <- c(50,100,150)
```

Using `toJSON` from the jsonlite package produces an array that does not preserve the numeric class of the count variable.:

```
toJSON(as.matrix(df))
[["Person A","50"],["Person B","100"],["Person C","150"]]
```

I fully recognize this is because converting `df` to a matrix requires all data to be of the same class. Instead, I would like the classes preserved such that `name` is preserved as a string and `count` is preserved as numeric, like so:

```
[["Person A",50],["Person B",100],["Person C",150]]
```

For some context, I'd like to be able to feed the JSON output externally to Google Charts (not through googleVis). Suggestions and help are so greatly appreciated- I've tried a number of things and can't quite seem to yield the product I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transform your data.frame to a paired list before transforming it to a json string. :

```
library(RJSONIO) 
## use  cat for better print
cat(toJSON(Map(function(x,y)list(x,y),df$name,df$count)))

[
 [
 "Person A",
    50 
],
[
 "Person B",
   100 
],
[
 "Person C",
   150 
] 
]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much- I was hung up on using jsonlite and did not consider JSONIO.

Comment: no I think thsis should work with `jsonlite` also. The main idea here is to use `Map` to transform your dataframe to a list.

Comment: Ah, got it. Apologies for my ignorance. Thanks again!